# Sanitize User Input in SAS

Tags: sas

What is a safe way to sanitize user input from SAS stored process parameters?

SAS stored processes can accept user input via parameters.  At a high level, these user inputs can contain special text that will cause issues in SAS.

For example, if a user inputs Bad"Text into a lastName, the following code is problematic:

```
Proc SQL;
  Select *
    From Foo
    Where Bar = "&LastName";
Quit;
```

Preventing this specific instance is easy, but what if the user is attempting to inject code.

Replacing all " in a macro variable isn't enough if the user includes targeted characters like '"%&.

Is there a robust solution towards escaping special characters in macro variables that later need to be used, in this case in the where clause of a pass through SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAS stored process server should already be protecting your SAS session from client attempted injections.

From ["SAS 9.1.3 Integration Technologies » Developer's Guide"](http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/dev_guide/stprocess/input.html)

> **Special Character Quoting**
>  Input parameter values are specified by the
>   stored process client at run time. The author of a stored process has
>   little control over the values a client can specify. Setting the
>   values directly into SAS macro variables would allow clients to insert
>   executable macro code into a stored process and could lead to
>   unexpected behavior or unacceptable security risks. For example, if an
>   input parameter named COMP was set to "Jones&Comp." and passed
>   directly into the macro variable, any references to &COMP in the
>   stored process program would lead to an invalid recursive macro
>   reference. To avoid this problem, stored process parameters are masked
>   with SAS macro quoting functions before being set into macro
>   variables. In the previous example, the parameter COMP would be set
>   with the equivalent of:
> `%let COMP=%nrstr(Jones&Comp.);`
>  The stored
>   process can then freely use &COMP without special handling for unusual
>   input values. Special characters that are masked for input parameters
>   are the ampersand (&), apostrophe ('), percent sign (%), quotation
>   marks ("), and semicolon (;).
>  There might be special cases where you
>   want to unmask some or all of the special characters in an input
>   parameter. The `STPSRV_UNQUOTE2` function unmasks only matched
>   apostrophe (') or quotation mark (") characters. This can be useful
>   for passing in parameters that are used as SAS options. The `%UNQUOTE`
>   macro function unquotes all characters in an input parameter, but you
>   should only use this function in very limited circumstances. You
>   should carefully analyze the potential risk from unexpected client
>   behavior before unquoting input parameters. Remember that stored
>   processes can be executed from multiple clients and some client
>   interfaces perform little or no checking of input parameter values
>   before they are passed to the stored process.
> **Note:** An input parameter
>   to a stored process executing on a workspace server cannot contain
>   both apostrophe (') and quotation mark (") characters. Attempting to
>   set such an input parameter will result in an error.

If for some reason a macro value becomes unquoted I would recommend using `%SUPERQ(myMacroVar)` which resolve the value in a manner more safe than `&myMacroVar`

Having a 'test bed' that checks a stored process (which at the simplest interpretation is just a macro) outside a stored process server may lead you to think the injection is possible because the test bed may not quote the parameters in the same way the server would.

Comment: One unanticipated injection risk comes from storing stored process parameter values in a data set and then using them again at a later time as part of a html code construct or other SAS evaluation scope.  User input that is stored and re-used should be quoted for the scope in which the evaluation occurs.  This may mean `superq` or `htmlencode` will be needed at either use time or data storage time.